# Getting an auto increment id and using that in a different query with the same submit

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a register page that I initially just had one query going to a db table called 'users'. In the 'users' table I have a column called 'id' that is a primary auto increment field.

I then created a new query under my original that will send to a db table called 'payment status'. Everything in this query is working other than my attempt to use the 'id' created by the 'users' table and to put that into my 'payment_status' db table for the column 'user_id'. It always enters a 0 value in it.

```
if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {
                $user->create(array(
                    'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                    'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                $success = "You have successfully created an account. We will notify you once the account has been approved. Then you will be able to login.";
                echo $success;

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                $error;
            }
        }
```

My second query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$firstname = Input::get('firstname');
$payment_name = "Owes";
$payment_id = 1;
$payment_amount = 0;

//Query to add user's name to owes db table

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die(' Owes DB prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('Owes DB bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }   
}
```

I'm trying to get it with this variable in my second prepared statement..

```
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
```

So I am trying to get the 'id' from the 'users' table and use that for the 'user_id' in the 'payment_status' table.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQLi, so you can use `mysqli::$insert_id` to get the last ID inserted into the database.

```
<?php

    // Connect to MySQL database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

    // Insert into database
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    $stmt->execute();


    // Debug
    var_dump($con->insert_id);

    // Output:
    // int(1)
```

Comment: This is only dumping the id for the payment_status table. I want to get the id from the users table and insert that into the user_id column of the payment_status table.